# send a certain portion to a specific address with every transaction

Tags: solidity, sendtransaction

i have created a Smartcontract.  now i want the functionality: where 2.5% of every transaction is transferred to a fixed address. say the address is 0x809341c1c1cba2d6accf8188bca463a119443d. i know it can be done from `transfer()` and `transferFrom()`. but could not able to sum up the code.

here is the contract

```
     `pragma solidity ^0.5.0;


contract ERC20Interface {
    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance);
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining);
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
}

safe math---------------------------------------------------------------------------
......................
/////////

    


contract me is ERC20Interface, SafeMath {
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals; // 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it

    uint256 public _totalSupply;

    mapping(address => uint) balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;

    
    constructor() public {
        name = "me";
        symbol = "me";
        decimals = 18;
        _totalSupply = 250000000000000000000000000;

        balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _totalSupply);
    }

    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint) {
        return _totalSupply  - balances[address(0)];
    }

    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance) {
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }

    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining) {
        return allowed[tokenOwner][spender];
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        return true;
    }

    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
        balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[from] = safeSub(balances[from], tokens);
        allowed[from][msg.sender] = safeSub(allowed[from][msg.sender], tokens);
        balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
        emit Transfer(from, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Will recommend you this: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol

Comment: does that contract has the functionality?

Comment: I was suggesting to use inherit your contract from there. The rest of the functionality is simple. Not sure why you need it. :)

Comment: i just need it...can you show me how to write code for that.

Comment: It is not possible as `transfer()` and `transferFrom()` are public functions and cannot be overrided in openzeppelin implementation of ERC20.

You can still achieve it by changing the actual implementation of openzeppelin ERC20.

Comment: plz show me how to do it...